# Should increase/decrease token supply on transfer to/from 0x0?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, mint, erc-1155

I am about both ERC-20 and ERC-1155.

Should `totalSupply` be increased/decreased, when:

- transferring to 0x0?
- burning an amount already placed at 0x0 address?

By the way, should 0x0 be allowed to have non-zero balance?

Answer (score 0):

For ERC-20:

- transferring to 0x0? - No, `totalSupply` shouldn't change upon transfer
- burning an amount already placed at 0x0 address? - Yes, `totalSupply` should decrease upon burn (though I'm not sure how exactly you are planning to trigger that to begin with)
- should 0x0 be allowed to have non-zero balance? - Yes

For ERC-1155, I believe that all answers are the same.